# c# Split string using another string as delimiter and include delimiter as part of the splitted string

Tags: c#, regex, split

I need to split an input string using c# regex.
need to know how to include the delimiter content in the output as given below.

input:

```
string content="heading1: contents with respect to heading1 heading2: heading2 contents heading3: heading 3 related contents sample strings";

string[] delimters = new string[] {"heading1:","heading2:","heading3:"};
```

Expected output:

```
outputArray[0] = heading1: contents with respect to heading1
outputArray[1] = heading2: heading2 contents
outputArray[2] = heading3: heading 3 related contents sample strings
```

What I tried:

```
var result = content.Split(delimters,StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);
```

Output I got:

```
result [0]: " contents with respect to heading1 "
result [1]: " heading2 contents "
result [2]: " heading 3 related contents sample strings"
```

I couldnt find an API in string.split or in Regex to split as the expect result.

Comment: Please post the failing regex, else the question is offtopic and must be closed.

Comment: start googling for the following `IndexOf(), string.Split(), and string.Join()` functions.. good luck

Comment: Something like http://rextester.com/MSCV9884

Comment: This `\S+:.*?(?=\S+:|$)` could work for your case.

Comment: @MethodMan: thanks. I am reading more about regex to find a optimal solution. once i found i will post the answer.

Comment: @Thefourthbird: thanks for the answer.

Comment: this is my first question in stackoverflow. i didnt expect this quick worth replies. i will consider all the solutions and choose a fastest one. since the content size is big. thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may use a positive lookahead based solution:

```
var result = Regex.Split(content, $@"(?={string.Join("|", delimiters.Select(m => Regex.Escape(m)))})")
                  .Where(x => !string.IsNullOrEmpty(x))
```

See the [C# demo](https://ideone.com/Ii5O8j):

```
var content="heading1: contents with respect to heading1 heading2: heading2 contents heading3: heading 3 related contents sample strings";
var delimiters = new string[] {"heading1:","heading2:","heading3:"};
Console.WriteLine(
    string.Join("\n", 
        Regex.Split(content, $@"(?={string.Join("|", delimiters.Select(m => Regex.Escape(m)))})")
             .Where(x => !string.IsNullOrEmpty(x))
    )
);
```

Output:

```
heading1: contents with respect to heading1 
heading2: heading2 contents 
heading3: heading 3 related contents sample strings
```

The `(?={string.Join("|", delimiters.Select(m => Regex.Escape(m)))})` will construct a regex dynamically, it will look like

```
(?=heading1:|heading2:|heading3:)
```

See the [regex demo](http://regexstorm.net/tester?p=%28%3F%3Dheading1%3A%7Cheading2%3A%7Cheading3%3A%29&i=heading1%3A%20contents%20with%20respect%20to%20heading1%20heading2%3A%20heading2%20contents%20heading3%3A%20heading%203%20related%20contents%20sample%20strings). The pattern will basically match any position in the string that is followed with either `herring1:`,  `herring2:` or `herring3:` without consuming these substrings, so they will land in the output.

Note that `delimiters.Select(m => Regex.Escape(m))` is there to make sure all special regex metacharacters that might be in the delimiters are escaped and treated as literal chars by the regex engine.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of *splitting*, I suggest *matching* which we then can *order*:

```
private static IEnumerable<string> Solution(string source, string[] delimiters) {
  int from = 0;
  int length = 0;

  // Points at which we can split
  var points = delimiters
      .SelectMany(delimiter => Regex
        .Matches(source, delimiter)
        .OfType<Match>()
        .Select(match => match.Index)
        .Select(index => new {
          index = index,
          delimiter = delimiter,
        }))
      .OrderBy(item => item.index)
      .ThenBy(item => Array.IndexOf(delimiters, item.delimiter)); // tie break

  foreach (var point in points) {
    if (point.index >= from + length) {
      // Condition: we don't want the very first empty part
      if (from != 0 || point.index - from != 0)
        yield return source.Substring(from, point.index - from);

      from = point.index;
      length = point.delimiter.Length;
    }
  }

  yield return source.Substring(from);
}
```

Test:

```
string content = 
  "heading1: contents with respect to heading1 heading2: heading2 contents heading3: heading 3 related contents sample strings";

string[] delimiters = new string[] { 
  "heading1:", "heading2:", "heading3:" };

Console.WriteLine(Solution(content, delimiters));
```

Outcome:

```
heading1: contents with respect to heading1 
heading2: heading2 contents 
heading3: heading 3 related contents sample strings
```

In case we split by digits (2nd test)

```
Console.WriteLine(Solution(content, new string[] {"[0-9]+"}));
```

We'll get

```
heading
1: contents with respect to heading
1 heading
2: heading
2 contents heading
3: heading 
3 related contents sample strings
```

Answer (score 0):

```
string content = "heading1: contents with respect to heading1 heading2: heading2 contents heading3: heading 3 related contents sample strings";
string[] delimters = new string[] { "heading1:", "heading2:", "heading3:" };

var dels = string.Join("|", delimters);
var pattern = "(" + dels + ").*?(?=" + dels + "|\\Z)";

var outputArray = Regex.Matches(content, pattern);

foreach (Match match in outputArray)
    Console.WriteLine(match);
```

The pattern is the following:

```
(heading1:|heading2:|heading3:).*?(?=heading1:|heading2:|heading3:|\Z)
```

It looks like the answer of Wiktor Stribiżew.
And of course we should use `Regex.Escape`, as he has shown.